# Convert PNG to black and white GIF with gd or imagemagick

Tags: php, gd, gif, imagick, barcode-printing

I am generating barcodes in a PHP webpage with the [Picqer library](https://github.com/picqer/php-barcode-generator), which can output to PNG, JPG, SVG or HTML.

On-screen they look great and are readable with the wand, but when printing they are apparently dithered, preventing them from being read.

If I save the generated PNG image to a file and use Photoshop to convert it to GIF (no transparency, 0 dither, 2 colors), then re-open the image with the browser and print, I get a perfect, crisp image with no dithering.

So I tried converting directly to GIF with the gd library in PHP:

```
// Create a GD image from the PNG generated by getBarcode. ($result = the Picqer\Barcode\BarcodeGeneratorPNG::getBarcodeoutput
    $gd_image = imagecreatefromstring($result);

    // Convert to palette image with no dithering and 2 colors
    imagetruecolortopalette($gd_image, false, 2);

    // Output the image as a GIF:
    header('Content-Type: image/gif');
    imagegif($gd_image, false); // Output directly to browser
```

However, this generates an exact duplicate of the PNG - when printed, it's dithered.

How can I fix this in order to generate a 2-color GIF with no dithering and no transparency?  I think this would solve the output clarity issue.  If there's a better way, I'm open to it.

I'm also open to using other image processing libraries like Imagick if that would be a better choice.

Thanks!

**UPDATE #1:**
OK so I have made *some* progress: I switched to Image Magick and performed the following conversion from the original PNG file to a 2-color, non-dithered GIF, which renders a beautifully clean and crisp black and white image:

```
$im = new Imagick();
    $im->readImageBlob($result);    // convert string to Imagic

    // Quantize:
    $im->quantizeImage(2, imagick::COLORSPACE_GRAY, 1, false, false);

    // Output image as GIF
    $im->setIMageFormat('gif');
    header("Content-Type: image/gif");
    echo $im->getImageBlob();
```

**PROBLEM:** this method seems to be very resource-intensive.  When I request a page filled with barcode images (20-30 qty) several of the images appear as "broken", generating http 500 errors "end of script output before headers".

I assume this means the Imagick routines are using hefty memory/cpu resources, so when the browser requests lots of images at once, PHP is reaching the limits of its resources.

**UPDATE #2:**
Performance tests reveal that Imagick is the bottleneck:
Generating 133 barcodes on a single HTML page, in PNG format:
Average time to execute getBarcode() function: 733uS
Average time to echo result: 13uS

Generating same 133 barcodes using the Imagick conversion listed above:
getBarcode() - avg 1mS
Conversion to GIF: **avg 0.76 S**

So I wonder why Imagick is so slow... ?  These are *tiny* files, on the order of 200 bytes (PNG).

SAMPLE INPUT PNG IMAGE: [image: Sample Barcode]

Comment: hi Ryan, look if this topic help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142477/php-converting-pngs-and-gifs-into-grayscale

Comment: It's somewhat like what I was doing with GD to begin with.  However, it doesn't seem to actually reduce the color palette to 2 colors.  I need a 2-color GIF to be crisp when printed. This is proved by the Imagick code, which truly generates a 2-color GIF and is very crisp when printed.  The issue now is the Imagick performance.

Comment: Can you share a sample input image?

Comment: Please can you try reproducing this as a standalone CLI PHP script. If it is still slow, it would be appropriate to report it at https://github.com/mkoppanen/imagick/issues